# How can I get SSIS to view a drive mounted on a NAS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis-2012, bulk-load

I'm trying to rebuild an SSIS environment on a new server.  The existing environment uses a local drive for some data input, using SSIS to bulk load the data from csv files.

I'd like the new environment to use out relatively new NAS for this task.  The nas is mapped to a drive letter on Windows Server, both using my domain name and the generic dwarehouse domain name used to install the software.

When I execute the new package manually using Visual Studio the bulk load process cannot see the file.  If I copy the file from the NAS to a local drive, Visual Studio can see it.

I'm sure it's a matter of giving the right permissions to the correct user, but I can't figure out what user that should be.

FWIW, we are using SQL Server 2012 Data Warehouse Edition and Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It should use the credentials that started the package, unless the connection has different explicit credentials provided.  If it was started by a sql agent job, then it will run with the credentials the SQL Agent service runs with.  If it was run from a scheduled Windows task, then check the Task Scheduler credentials.

Follow it back to how the package was started and you should be able to identify what credentials it uses.

Comment: My problem at the moment is how to figure out what credentials Visual Studio is running the task as when I execute it in debug mode directly from Visual Studio.  I haven't gotten to the point of deploying it anywhere.

Comment: Download process explorer from Microsoft to see the credentials of the task.  If the credentials are different than your interactive session, you'll need to map the drive for the other user account as well.